# Coalesce vs Sargability

Tags: sql-server, database, performance

The company that I work for uses a third party software, and we don't have any exposure to the application code, so I cannot change much the DB objects.
I'm trying to do some work around in a view that is not Sarg, there is a coalesce to replace nulls to 0 within the view, and the view is called on the application, there is a filter on the same column.

- SQL Server version: 2005

The scenario is the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('test01' , 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE test01;

CREATE TABLE test01 ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY
                     , Parent NVARCHAR(100)
                     );
                     GO

IF OBJECT_ID('test02' , 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE test02;

CREATE TABLE test02 ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY
                    , ParentID INT 
                    , UserName NVARCHAR(100)
                    );
                    GO


ALTER TABLE test02 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_test02_ParentID FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES test02(ID);


INSERT INTO test01
          SELECT 'DGN010101'
UNION ALL SELECT 'DGN020202'
UNION ALL SELECT 'DGN030303'
UNION ALL SELECT 'DGN040404'
GO


INSERT INTO test02 (ParentID, UserName)
          SELECT 1, 'DGN010101'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'DGN020202'
UNION ALL SELECT NULL, 'DGN030303'
GO
```

First test - Sarg issue

```
--drop view vw_test 

CREATE VIEW vw_test 

AS

SELECT tmp1.ID as ParentID
     , tmp1.Parent
     , COALESCE(tmp2.ID, 0) as UserID
     , tmp2.UserName
FROM test01 tmp1
    LEFT JOIN test02 tmp2
        on tmp1.ID = tmp2.ID


------------------------
-- An index scan is performed 

SELECT ParentID
     , Parent
     , UserID
     , UserName
FROM vw_test
WHERE UserID = 1
```

Second test - No sarg issue

```
--drop view vw_test 

CREATE VIEW vw_test 

AS

    SELECT tmp1.ID as ParentID
         , tmp1.Parent
         , tmp2.ID as UserID
         , tmp2.UserName
    FROM test01 tmp1
        LEFT JOIN test02 tmp2
            on tmp1.ID = tmp2.ID

------------------------
-- Index seek is performed 

    SELECT ParentID
         , Parent
         , UserID
         , UserName
    FROM vw_test
    WHERE UserID = 1
```

- Things to remember:

  - I still need to replace NULLs by 0.
  - I cannot change how the view is called.

I appreciate any thought of you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ID column (UserID) of the test02 table does not allow NULLs, try this version:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_test2
AS
SELECT tmp1.ID as ParentID
     , tmp1.Parent
     , tmp2.ID as UserID
     , tmp2.UserName
FROM test01 tmp1
JOIN test02 tmp2
        on tmp1.ID = tmp2.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT tmp1.ID as ParentID
     , tmp1.Parent
     , 0 as UserID
     , tmp2.UserName
FROM test01 tmp1
LEFT JOIN test02 tmp2
        on tmp1.ID = tmp2.ID
WHERE tmp2.ID IS NULL;
GO
```

Comment: Beautiful! I tried different things but didn't think about this. Query is performing much faster now. 

Many thanks Dan!